# ¿Cómo hacer que un prompt imprima los resultados en una ventana dinámica?

Tags: javascript

Me gustaría que mi programa imprimiese los resultados introducidos por el usuario en una ventana dinámica, o sea, que se abriese una ventana con una serie de características (*altura 800px y esas cosas*) y mostrase los resultados en esa ventana, adjunto el código que llevo hecho hasta el momento:

```
var nombre;
  var edad;
  nombre=prompt('Ingrese su nombre y apellidos','');
  dia_de_nacimiento=prompt('Dia de nacimiento?');
  mes=prompt('mes?');
  ano=prompt('ano');
  document.write('Hola ');
  document.write(nombre,'<br>');
  document.write('Naciste:','<br>');
  document.write(dia_de_nacimiento);
  document.write(mes);
  document.write(ano);

var my_window;

function abrir()
{
      
 my_window = window.open("",
 "mywindow","status=1,width=350,height=150");

 document.write('Hola ');
 document.write(nombre,'<br>');
     
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.open()` retorna una referencia a la ventana abierta, dentro de esa ventana podes usar `document.write()` anteponiéndole la referencia a esa ventana, o retornar la referencia y usarla por fuera de la función, algo así:

```javascript
var nombre;
var edad;
nombre = prompt('Ingrese su nombre y apellidos', '');
dia_de_nacimiento = prompt('Dia de nacimiento?');
mes = prompt('mes?');
ano = prompt('ano');
document.write('Hola ');
document.write(nombre, '<br>');
document.write('Naciste:', '<br>');
document.write(dia_de_nacimiento);
document.write(mes);
document.write(ano);

var my_window;

function abrir() {

  my_window = window.open("",
    "mywindow", "status=1,width=350,height=150");

  my_window.document.write('Hola ');
  my_window.document.write(nombre, '<br>');
  my_window.document.write('Naciste:', '<br>');
  my_window.document.write(dia_de_nacimiento);
  my_window.document.write(mes);
  my_window.document.write(ano);

  return my_window;
}

var unawindow = abrir()
unawindow.document.write('<br><b>', 'Hola de nuevo', '</b><br>');
```

Podes ver [aquí un fiddle funcional](https://jsfiddle.net/5dq4x138/)